# O correto é portifólio, portfólio ou portfolio?

Tags: português-brasileiro, estrangeirismos, linguagem

Em vários sites ou locais vemos a palavra "*portfolio*" escrita de várias formas diferentes, mas qual delas é a correta?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Here's the meta topic on tags for dialects: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8/distinction-between-portuguese-variants It's suggested there that just [tag:brasil] be used.

Comment: @Frank I agree... I wait decline or accept current edition by Marcelo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que não seja a questão de certo e errado, mas sim são sinônimos conforme o [portoeditora.pt](http://www.portoeditora.pt/espacolinguaportuguesa/duvidas-da-lingua-portuguesa/detalhe-duvidas-lp/ver/portefolio-portfolio-ou-porta-folio-?id=26742&langid=1)

Entretanto o [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portf%C3%B3lio) afirma que 
*Portfólio*, *portfolio* são usado no *português brasileiro* e *portefólio*, *porta-fólio* no português europeu.

Tanto que se pesquisar no [VOLP](http://www.academia.org.br/abl/cgi/cgilua.exe/sys/start.htm?sid=23) notará que ele encontra as palavras *porta-fólio* e *Portfólio*:

> ### porta-fólio
>
> s.m.; pl. porta-fólios
>
> ---
>
> ### portfólio
>
> s.m.

Todas são corretas no *popular* e são sinônimos

Comment: Também concordo com isso, e geralmente as versões que vejo mais frequentemente a serem usadas são - **portfólio** e **portefólio** .

Answer (score 5):

O [VOLP](http://www.academia.org.br/abl/cgi/cgilua.exe/sys/start.htm?sid=23) registra a forma *portfólio* como sendo a correta.

Comment: [Guilherme's answer](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/482/156) is better detailed and explains that there are 3 correct synonyms, but _port**i**fólio_ is none of them.

Answer (score 4):

*Portfolio*, sem i e sem acento agudo, é a forma original da [palavra em inglês](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=portfolio&oq=portfolio&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=portfolio%20%2B%20english). Muitos defendem o seu uso justificando ser um estrangeirismo que deve ser usado na sua forma original. Lembrando que Portfolio em Português significa **Pasta**.

*Portfólio*, sem i e com acento agudo é a forma mais aceita como sendo aportuguesada.

---

Comment: Acho que você poderá ganhar mais pontos se colocar algumas referências na sua resposta para embasa-la. Não é obrigatório, é só uma sugestão que talvez lhe ajude.